# Can these logarithmic inequalities show existence of a prime between (x-1)^2 and x^2

Tags: inequalities, nt.number-theory

[SOME PROPERTIES OF THE SERIES OF COMPOSED NUMBERS, p2](http://www.emis.de/journals/EM/expmath/volumes/11/11.2/Garunkstis301.pdf) gives the bounds

$$l(x)=\frac{x}{\log(x)-28/29}<\pi(x) < u(x)=\frac{x}{\log(x)-1.12} \qquad (1)$$

for $x \geq 3299$.

[TWO GENERALIZATIONS OF LANDAU’S INEQUALITY, p6](http://files.ele-math.com/preprints/mia-15-52-pre.pdf) gives

$$x\pi(x) < 2 \pi(x^2) $$
for $x \geq 67$.

To show $\pi(x^2) > x\pi(x)/2 > \pi((x-1)^2)$ tried the bounds in (1) leading to:

$$xl(x) /2 > u((x-1)^2) \iff $$
$$  \frac{29\, x^{2}}{2 \, {\left(29 \, \log\left(x\right) - 28\right)}} - \frac{{\left(x - 1\right)}^{2}}{\log\left({\left(x - 1\right)}^{2}\right) - 1.12} >0 \qquad (2)$$

Experimentally the LHS of (2) is increasing up to $10^{120}$ and is quite large.

> 1. Is this reasoning correct?
> 2. Can (2) be proved?

All CAS I tried failed to solve (2) though the limit at infinity is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that, in the second paper, the inequality $$x\pi(x)<2\pi(x^2)$$
is derived from the inequality
$$xy\pi(x)\pi(y)>4\pi^2(xy)$$
by setting $x=y$. The proof for theorem 3 seems correct to me, so the sign flip is definitely a typo :)

Comment: Thanks. You mean the first formula is wrong in the paper?

Comment: Yes, it should be $x\pi(x)>2\pi(x^2)$.

Comment: Thanks. The corrected formula is much worse bound than the first paper, the sign flip explains this :)

Comment: Also, pi(100)=25 and pi(10,000)=1229, if memory serves.  The good practice of mathematics involves verification as well as extension and refactoring.  Gerhard "Let This Be A Lesson" Paseman, 2012.05.05